# Как в C# имитировать нажатие клавиши и кнопок мыши?

Tags: c#, c++, ввод

К примеру чтобы при нажатии Space у меня пару раз очень быстро нажималась левая кнопка мышки и/или клавиши на клавиатуре. Желательно в C#, если там такое нельзя сделать, то C++

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Erik, про С# не скажу, а C++ не имеет стандартных механизмов обработки событий. Для этого необходимо пользоваться сторонними фреймворками\библиотеками, например Qt,Boost и др

Comment: И это надо делать когда ваше приложение в фоне/свернуто или в окне вашего приложения? Если да, то https://stackoverflow.com/a/604417/12888024. Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Чтобы имитировать ввод, есть Win API `SendInput` или уже готовый NuGet пакет для C# **InputSimulator**.

Comment: @Artem.rtv, каким боком тут фреймвёрки? Ему winapi надо.